# Django-Python Instance of 'Object' has not 'value' member even if I instantiate

Tags: python, django

With the following definition:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):

    ...
    title = models.CharField(
        _('Title'),
        max_length=200,
        )

    queue = models.ForeignKey(
        Queue,
        verbose_name=_('Queue'),
        )

    created = models.DateTimeField(
        _('Created'),
        blank=True,
        help_text=_('Date this ticket was first created'),
        )

    modified = models.DateTimeField(
        _('Modified'),
        blank=True,
        help_text=_('Date this ticket was most recently changed.'),
        )

    submitter_email = models.EmailField(
        _('Submitter E-Mail'),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text=_('The submitter will receive an email for all public '
                    'follow-ups left for this task.'),
        )

    assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(
        MongoUser,
        related_name='assigned_to',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name=_('Assigned to'),
        )

    ...
```

And this Instantiation:

```
ticket = Ticket(
        title="aaaaa",
        submitter_email=request.POST['submitter_email'],
        assigned_to= contableHelpdesk,
        status=1,
        queue=queue,
        description=request.POST['body'],
        priority=request.POST['priority'],
    )

    print(ticket.title)
    print(ticket.submitter_email)
    print(ticket.queue)
    ticket.save()
```

Ticket is not getting the correct values, I checked that types match.
When 'prints', ticket.title says Instance of 'Ticket' has not 'title' member and so on with submitter_email and queue.

POST

Variable    Value
queue
'2'
title
'Ticket Test'
submitter_email 
'*****@gmail.com'
body
'Ticket test'
priority
'3'
due_date_day
'0'
due_date_month
'0'
due_date_year
'0'
attachment
''

Comment: Make sure you have imported the right `Ticket`.

Comment: It is:
`from helpdesk.models import Ticket, Queue, UserSettings, KBCategory, MongoUser`

Comment: Any wildcard imports?

Comment: @KlausD. Solved, I was making wildcard import from another models.py.
Why is this problem?

Comment: If that model also has a `Ticket` and the wildcard import comes after the original one, it will overwrite the `Ticket`. This is why you shouldn't use wildcard import. It's not trivial to debug problems.

Comment: Totally unrelated, but django has forms that make userdata validation and sanitization much safer AND much easier, and even modelforms that know how to create / update a model instance. So do yourself, your app's users and anyone that's going to have to maintain this code a favour : **use dango forms**.